# My Automator Workflow fails because it fails to find the git command within the 'Run Shell Script' command? Need help

Tags: automator, bash, script, command-line, git

I have an Automator workflow and one of the actions is to clone a repository. Here's the code for the 'Run Shell Script' action. The command is run within the Bash shell `/bin/bash` if that matters:

```
SOURCEDIR="${3/\/Volumes/}"

cd "$2"
REPOURL="bob@somedomain.com:$SOURCEDIR"
WORKINGDIR="$1"

# Capture any errors with cloning process in log file
git clone "$REPOURL" "$WORKINGDIR" &> ./log.txt

// For debugging
echo "exit code: $?"
echo "PPID: $PPID"

open .
```

Now the Automator App runs fine on my machine. The path to git on my machine (A Macbook Pro) is: `/usr/bin/git` (I believe I installed git on my machine through Xcode)

But on my co-worker's machine (Also a Mac Pro) the Automator App fails. In fact, the output of the log.txt file says: `bash: git: command not found`

Now on my co-worker's machine the path to git is: `usr/local/git/bin`, which, yes, is different because he installed git through the Google Git Installer for Mac OS X, but I didn't think it should matter because in the script the git command is not absolute path to the command and further more my co-worker can run git normally from a Bash script but when invoked directly from the Terminal.

So what gives? Why does the automator workflow work for me but not for my co-worker?

There must be something fundamental about Bash or Unix that I'm not understanding here but I'm lost.

Answer (score 60):

Scripts run via Automator use the default search path which usually does not include `/usr/local/bin`. In your case an easy fix would be to put

```bash
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

somewhere at the beginning of the script.

PS: People using Homebrew on an Apple Silicon Mac should also add

```bash
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 21):

For a more general solution to the bash environment in automator differing from your own you could simply load your personal bash profile at the first line of the automator bash script:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

This will make the path and any other environment variables you're used to using available from your automator script.

Comment: I much prefer this solution. A good overview of the bash login scripts is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/415444/1515564)

Comment: Struggling to make this work for zsh, source ~/.zprofile didn't help

Comment: I had to use source ~/.zshrc

Comment: I think this is much better than just exporting $PATH, because there may be many more settings in your bash profile, so the same script may behave differently in Automator vs. in Terminal without `source ~/.bash_profile` or `source ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: This won't actually add /urs/local/bin to your path unless for some reason you've added it to your path in .bash_profile. On macOS, /usr/local/bin typically gets added to your path because it's included as a line in /etc/paths.

Answer (score 7):

I solved the same problem of the same "service" workflows being run on differently configured machines by checking what happens when the terminal starts the shell and eventually adding the following snippet to the top of all my "Run Shell Script" actions:

```
if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
    eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi
if  [ -f "$HOME"/.profile ]; then
    source "$HOME"/.profile
elif [ -f "$HOME"/.bash_profile ]; then
    source "$HOME"/.bash_profile
elif [ -f "$HOME"/.bashrc ]; then
    source "$HOME"/.bashrc
fi
```

This covers all the cases I've encountered so far.

Comment: The only answer that works for me under all cases. Thank you 

Comment: Since Apple doesn't like bash anymore these days, this answer should probably be updated for the shell, which is currently en vogue at Apple. Need to find time to do this (I still use bash)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why any of the other answers were not working for me, but if you use homebrew then put this at the start of the Automator script.

```
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Because you are using an M1 Mac where Homebrew installs into `/opt/homebrew` instead of `/usr/local`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the Workflow to work on both machines that have git in different locations, then add each location to the PATH variable that patrix mentioned, separated by a `:`, as explained here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/AutomatorConcepts/Articles/ShellScriptActions.html

So, at the very top of your Workflow Shell Script, you would add:

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
export PATH
```