# Bash script not working on Automator but working from terminal

Tags: automator, bash

I have this bash script that works perfectly on terminal

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in "$@"; do

  DIRNAME="$(dirname "$f")"

  filename=$(basename "$f")
  name="${filename%.*}"
  extension="${filename##*.}"

  /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i "$f" -filter_complex 'scale=1920:1080, pad=2134:1200:107:60' "$DIRNAME"/OUTPUT_"$name"."$extension"
  /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i OUTPUT_"$name"."$extension" -vf 'scale=1920:1080' FINAL_"$name"."$extension"

 done
```

I am trying to create a service for finder that accept movie files and process them using this script. The service is setup to pass input to stdin. When I select movies on finder and run that service, nothing happens. Like I said, the script works perfectly from terminal.

[image]

Any clues?

---

This question appears to similar to [ffmpeg working from command line in Terminal but not in an Automator shell script!](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130837/ffmpeg-working-from-command-line-in-terminal-but-not-in-an-automator-shell-scrip?rq=1) but applying the answer (full path to `ffmpeg`) did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to specifying the full path to `ffmpeg` two additional problems needed to be solved:

1. The path to the output files are also needed.
2. The `pass input` option of the shell script action has to be set `as arguments`.

[image]

The final script is then this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in "$@"; do

  DIRNAME="$(dirname "$f")"

  filename=$(basename "$f")
  name="${filename%.*}"
  extension="${filename##*.}"

  /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i "$f" -filter_complex 'scale=1920:1080, pad=2134:1200:107:60' "$DIRNAME"/OUTPUT_"$name"."$extension"
  /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i "$DIRNAME"/OUTPUT_"$name"."$extension" -vf 'scale=1920:1080' "$DIRNAME"/FINAL_"$name"."$extension"


done
```

Notice how the path was added to ffmpeg and also that `$DIRNAME` was added to the output files, that was not mentioned by the other question.